# Custom Validation - if statement

Tags: angular, custom-validators

A newbie here. just wanted to ask what is the meaning of the code below.

```
if((control.value as string).indexOf(' ') >=0)
```

I was doing some self-study and I could not understand it. Appreciate if you give a hand to explain it at a very low level.

here the full code;

```
export class UsernameValidators {
    static connotContainSpace( control: AbstractControl) : ValidationErrors | null {
// this is the part when the validation is stated

    if((control.value as string).indexOf(' ') >=0)
     return { cannotContainSpace: true }

    return null; 
}
```

Comment: It checks to see if there is a space in the value

Answer (score 4):

I am trying to explain you using a simple example:

```
control.value = "This is stackoverflow";
```

`.indexOf(' ')` will find the first index number for space substring in `control.value`

like in our example first space is present in index number 4, which is greater than zero , then if statement will execute.

Comment: `if` isn't a function.

Comment: Thank  you.. understood =)

Answer (score 2):

```
if((control.value as string).indexOf(' ') >=0)
```

Lets breakdown the above code  statement one at a time.

- `control.value as string`

The above code converts the content of **control.value** as a **string** datatype

- (control.value as string).indexOf(' ')

***indexOf*** is a method available on  *string* datatype. It returns the index of the first occurrence of the string/character specified in the parameter. If the string/character is not found then it will return -1 else any value above zero or zero itself.

In the above example the character is ' ' i.e. **space character**.

- if((control.value as string).indexOf(' ') >=0)

The if statement checks if the value returned is greater than or equal to zero. if the value is true it implies that the character **space** was found in the string value of **control.value**

Comment: Thanks for the help Sir